# CABasicAnimation animates but the views frame is not persistent

Tags: cabasicanimation, caanimation

I have been playing with CABasicAnimation and CAAnimationGroup today, and I am already in love with it. I have couple of basic animations happening, in which the circle shape shrinks and also downscale to rounded square shape, just like "Voice memo" application in iOS 7.

Below is the code for it.

```
CABasicAnimation *corner = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"cornerRadius"];
corner.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction     functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
corner.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:recordingShape.layer.cornerRadius];
corner.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:30.0f];
corner.duration = 1.0;


//shrinking - scaling
CABasicAnimation* shrink = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
shrink.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.5];
shrink.duration = 0.5;


// Two animations concurrently so set up CAAnimationGroup
CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
[group setDuration:0.5];
[group setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:shrink, corner, nil]];

// Animate the layer
[[recordingShape layer] addAnimation:group forKey:@"bounceAndFade"];
```

The animation occurs nicely as expected, but after animation it goes back to its original state as round circle, could anyone guide me as of how can I persist the layer's frame?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well I Didn't know you could setup a delegate for the CAAnimationGroup group, hence I change the actual cornerRadius and transform at animationDidStop call.